# Graph API search not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, search

Earlier i was searching for students of a particular institute on facebook using -

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=sgsits&type=user&access_token=abcd..
```

But it has now stopped working.This search now returns an empty data array.Why?

Comment: there is a space between sgsits and &type, is this space also in your code?

Comment: no there is no space in my code

Comment: i am indian @ClintonWard

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if your access token has expired?

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/

They expire after two hours.

Comment: No the access token didn't expire.I have the access token with two months validity

Comment: Hi,is it working now or is it still returning an empty array?